# How would I avoid the "expected 2 inputs" when using a list in the interface for this code?

Tags: netlogo

The compiler posts " If expected 2 inputs , a true/false and a command block". How should this code be changed to avoid this?

```
if EDIT_TOOL = "Road" ask patches[set pcolor black]
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if EDIT_TOOL = "Road" 
[
ask patches[set pcolor black]
]
```

A block is defined by "[" and "]". In netlogo unlike in 'c' like languages they are not optional even for single expressions.

"End" is only used at the end of procedures.